# Methods for dynamic user input for a database in SQLite

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

How can I create a dynamic SQLite format for users to create and delete database columns

For example, let's say on the activity screen it is initially:

```
Trial 1:   Input 1   Input 2
```

But after an "add row" button is clicked it adds another row like below

```
Trial 1:   Input 1   Input 2
Trial 2:   Input 1   Input 2
```

But if the user wanted to delete the second row, it would go back to the initial state.
I added images at the bottom to sort of show what I mean.

I only started learning how to use Android Studio so I was thinking that I can just set the original SQLite entities to have 20 Columns, assuming that two columns would represent each input of each trial and also assuming that they wouldn't do anything beyond 10 trials. But since I don't know how many trials the user would input, if the user were to have more than 10, it would be a problem.

Would this be right? Or is there a way for the "add row" button click to dynamically add two extra columns in the database for each input. Or would I need two different databases that save each input to each database with the same ID and get the values through same primary key id?
Here are images:

Initially:

[image: Image 1]

After button click:

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would this be right? Or is there a way for the "add row" button click to dynamically add two extra columns in the database for each input.

You might want consider not try to dynamically manage a list but to rather utilise a **ListView** to list current data along with a single set of EditTexts for the input of new data.

> Or would I need two
>   different databases that save each input to each database with the
>   same ID and get the values through same primary key id?

In between columns and database there are tables. So as the issue appears to be adding a variable number of trials to experiments. Then a trial iswithin an experiment so you would probably have an experiment table and a trial table, with the latter referencing a single parent experiment to which the trial belongs.

Multiple databases. You very likely don't want the complications nor is there likely any need.

## Example

Here's a Working Example (albeit it very basic especially layout wise) that has a number of experiments to which trials can be added. The code adds 3 experiments for demonstration, named Experiment 1, Experiment 2 and Experiment 3.

When first run no trials will exist for any of the experiments. They can be added after entering the data (2 Edit Texts) and clicking the ADD button. At the top The Experiment name is display and there is a NEXT button clicking this will cycle through the experiments and display the trials for the experiment (if any).

The number of trials per experiment are unlimited.

## The Code

## Layout

First the layout **activity_main.xml**, which has

- a title (the ubiquitous Hello World)
- two EditTexts and a Button for adding new data.
- a ListView for listing the data in the database.

The code is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/experimentsection"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFAAAAFF">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentexperiment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No Experiment"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextexperiment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="NEXT"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/inputsection"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ADD"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/currentdata"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

## Database Helper

The Database Helper **DBHelper.java**, which defines a single table that has 3 columns

- an id column tha uniquely identifies a row.

  - (note the ListView's adapter requires this to be named _id)
- columns data1 and data1 for the 2 values hat will be stored

The code is :-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TBL_EXPERIMENT = "experiment";
    public static final String COL_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_EXPERIMENT_NAME = "experiment_name";

    public static final String TBL_MYTABLE1 = "mytable1";
    public static final String COL_EXPERIMENT_REF = "experiment_ref";
    public static final String COl_DATA1 = "data1";
    public static final String COL_DATA2 = "data2";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onConfigure(db);
        db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_EXPERIMENT + "(" +
                COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COL_EXPERIMENT_NAME + " TEXT UNIQUE" +
                ")"
        );
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_MYTABLE1 + "(" +
                COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +

                COL_EXPERIMENT_REF + " INTEGER " +
                " REFERENCES " + TBL_EXPERIMENT + "(" +
                COL_ID +
                ")," +

                COl_DATA1 + " TEXT," +
                COL_DATA2 + " TEXT" +
                ")"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public long addExperiment(String name) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_EXPERIMENT_NAME,name);
        return mDB.insert(TBL_EXPERIMENT,null,cv);
    }

    public long addTrial(long expermientId, String data1, String data2) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_EXPERIMENT_REF,expermientId);
        cv.put(COl_DATA1,data1);
        cv.put(COL_DATA2,data2);
        return mDB.insert(TBL_MYTABLE1,null ,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getAllRowsForAnExperiment(long experimentId) {
        String whereclause = COL_EXPERIMENT_REF + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(experimentId)};
        return mDB.query(TBL_MYTABLE1,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
    }


    public Cursor getAllExperiments() {
        return mDB.query(TBL_EXPERIMENT,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    public int deleteTrial(long id) {
        String whereclause = COL_ID + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
        return mDB.delete(TBL_MYTABLE1,whereclause,whereargs);
    }
}
```

- **addRow**is the method used  to add a row of data.
- **getAllRows** is the method used to retrieve all data.

## The Activity

Finally putting it all together is **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Define Class variables
    DBHelper mDBHlpr;
    Cursor mCursor, mExperiments;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;
    EditText mInput1, mInput2;
    TextView mExperimentName;
    Button mAdd, mNextExperiment;
    ListView mListView;

    long mCurrentExperimentId = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // Set the layout to be displayed

        //Instaniate the layout objects to be used
        mExperimentName = this.findViewById(R.id.currentexperiment);
        mNextExperiment = this.findViewById(R.id.nextexperiment);
        mInput1 = this.findViewById(R.id.input1);
        mInput2 = this.findViewById(R.id.input2);
        mAdd = this.findViewById(R.id.add);
        mListView = this.findViewById(R.id.currentdata);

        //Instantiate the Database helper
        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);
        addSomeExperiments();
        mExperiments = mDBHlpr.getAllExperiments();

        // Do the work
        manageExperimentButton();
        manageListView();
        manageAddButton();
    }

    /**
     * Manage the list view,
     * call this anytime the list is to be created (only once)
     * or the list is changed (e.g. after adding)
     */
    private void manageListView() {
        mCursor = mDBHlpr.getAllRowsForAnExperiment(mCurrentExperimentId); // Get the current data

        // If the Adapter hasn't been instantiated do so
        if (mSCA == null) {
            mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                    mCursor,
                    new String[]{DBHelper.COl_DATA1, DBHelper.COL_DATA2},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2},
                    0
            );
            mListView.setAdapter(mSCA); // Tie the adpater to the listview
            //<<<<<<<<< EXTRA DELETE A ROW WHEN LONG CLICKED >>>>>>>>>>
            mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    if(mDBHlpr.deleteTrial(id) > 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        manageListView();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"NOT deleted????",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    return true; // set this event as having been actioned
                }
            });
        } else {
            // If adapter has been instantiated tell it that the data has changed
            mSCA.swapCursor(mCursor);
        }
    }

    //Handle the Add button by adding an onClick listener
    private void manageAddButton() {
        mAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //First thing check if there is data to be added
                if (mInput1.getText().toString().length() < 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"No data in Input1. Try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mInput1.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                if (mInput2.getText().toString().length() < 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"No data in Input2. Try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mInput2.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                // If there is data to be added, try adding it
                // if the value returned from addRow is less than 1 or more then data was added
                if (mDBHlpr.addTrial(mCurrentExperimentId, mInput1.getText().toString(),mInput2.getText().toString()) > 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // As data has been added refresh the ListView
                    manageListView();
                    // and clear the input fields
                    mInput1.setText("");
                    mInput2.setText("");
                    // and finally position the focus on the first input
                    mInput1.requestFocus();
                } else {
                    // Ooops something went wrong (very unlikely with the current db schema)
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Not Added????",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private void manageExperimentButton() {
        mExperiments = mDBHlpr.getAllExperiments();
        mExperiments.moveToFirst();
        handleCurrentExperiment();
        mNextExperiment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               if(!mExperiments.moveToNext()) {
                   mExperiments.moveToFirst();
               }
                handleCurrentExperiment();
            }
        });
    }

    private void handleCurrentExperiment() {
        mCurrentExperimentId = mExperiments.getLong(mExperiments.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COL_ID));
        mExperimentName.setText(mExperiments.getString(mExperiments.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COL_EXPERIMENT_NAME)));
        manageListView();
    }

    //When the activity finishes close the cursor
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mCursor.close();
    }

    //If returning to the activity refresh the ListView
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        manageListView();
    }

    private void addSomeExperiments() {
        // Add some experiments if none exist
        if(DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase(),DBHelper.TBL_EXPERIMENT) > 0 ) return;
        mDBHlpr.addExperiment("Experiment 1");
        mDBHlpr.addExperiment("Experiment 2");
        mDBHlpr.addExperiment("Experiment 3");
    }
}
```

## Result

A screen shot of an experiment with close over 20 trials (A-Z were added) (albeit useless infromation). The code also includes deleting trials by long clicking on them in the list (as can be seen some have been deleted e.g trial E has been deleted) :

[image]

Clicking on NEXT takes you to Experiment 1, which has fewer trials :-

[image]

Comment: Hmmmm. What if these input were all part of an experiment. So like on the main activity, you click on the experiment name which leads you to the second page where the trial 1, input1 and input 2 are found. So this data is for its unique experiment?

Comment: @hsc You probably have an experiment table and each trial would reference/map to/ associate with the experiment.

Comment: @hsc answer changed to to include Experiments (3).

Comment: its to my understanding from looking at the code that the foreign key sets the experiment table as the parent table to the trial table. So if I were to use Room database then I can just use @ForeignKey

Comment: @hsc yes you can use `@ForeignKey`, it's not a requirement though, you can still associate/reference/map without a foreign key. It sets a rule saying that you cannot insert a value into the child column that is not a value in the referenced parent column. The ON DELETE CASCADE and ON UPDATE CASCADE can make things simple (forgot to add them for the demo).